# Understanding closed ball in the discrete metric system

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a discrete metric space and $x \in X$. Describe the open ball $B(x,1)$ and the closed ball $B[x,r]$.

I understand the first ball. If distance is between $0$ and $1$ then we say that $y$ is any element of ball then  $x=y$ .

I don't understand the second ball. When we think the same as like open ball ,then $x=y$ but it also can be $1$ so this cause $X$(the whole set).How to select which one is answer ? And how can it be whole set, is this whole set is just center which is radius 1  or different thing?

Comment: 'Show B(x,1)  and B[x,r]'  is not a question.

Comment: how to write this part , ı dont know what I can write .maybe set of solution is okey?

Comment: Does $B[x,r]$ denote the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$?

Comment: yes, our teacher denotes closed ball in this way

Comment: You may divide into cases according to whether $0 \leq r < 1$ or $r \geq 1$.

Comment: I understand 0≤r<1, the solution is only x=y becasue distence can be either 0 or 1 and in this way distance is 0 so x=y

Comment: But I dont understand r≤1  this situation  because it include both whole set and only point like in the previous .Which one do ı take as an answer

Comment: Also, if answer is a whole set , which means that is only circle with radius one or different thing.

Comment: Certainly $B[x,r] = X$ if $r \geq 1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144996/discussion-between---and-luxerhia).

Comment: In a matric space $(M,d)$, an open ball is a set $$B(x,r)=\{y\in M : d(x,y)<r\}$$

And a closed ball is a set
$$\overline{B}(x,r)=\{y\in M : d(x,y)\leq r\}$$

Split into four cases:

* $r=0$,
* $0<r<1$,
* $r=1$,
* $r>1$

And think about how the open and closed balls will differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $0<r<1$ we have $B(x,r)=\{x\}$ and $B[x,r]=\{x\}$. Now for $r=1$ we have $B(x,r)=\{x\}$ and $B=[x,r]=X$. And finally for $r>1$ we have $B(x,r)=B[x,r]=X$.